# How to see the image view's content from top

Tags: android, imageview

Hey guys I have this layout where there is a touch image view loaded from the internet, when the phone is in portrait mode everything is ok, but when in landscape the the middle part of the image appears (I have to scroll up to see it from the beginning) how is it possible to scroll up programmatically

here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/top"
        layout="@layout/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/title_top"
        layout="@layout/title_top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerIndicatorlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_top"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/spinner_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerIndicators"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCountrylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerIndicatorlayout"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:background="@color/spinner_background"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCountries"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ids.undp.classes.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivInfographics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerCountrylayout"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"

        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/defaultbg" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: it's a touch image view, it can be scrolled, i dont need a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setScrollPosition:

```
public void setScrollPosition(float focusX, float focusY) {
        setZoom(normalizedScale, focusX, focusY);
    }
```

Comment: when i enter as landscape it works fine, but when i enter as protrait and then change to landscape it doesn't scroll all the way up i even tried to pass negative values as parameters and it didn't work